# Any way to make these if statements more succinct?

Tags: python, if-statement

I made a small python program to tell whether a given number is positive or negitive, I'm trying to find a way to simplify it.

**Input :**

```
Number = int(input("Enter your number: "))
if Number>0:
    Value = 'Positive'
if Number<0:
    Value = 'Negitive'
if Number == 0:
    Value = 'Zero'

print (Value)
```

**Output:**

```
Enter your number:  5
Positive

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Replace last 2 *if*s by *elif*s.

Comment: Your code is already as simplified as it can be. Unless you want to use dictionaries, your code cannot be simplified..

Comment: Also I highly recommend that you follow standard naming conventions: your variable names should start with lowercase letters.

Comment: If you're looking for a more advanced syntax, ```value = "Positive" if number > 0 else "Negative" if number < 0 else "Zero"``` but honestly, sometimes the clear, straightforward way is better.

Comment: `value = 'positive' if number>0 else 'negative' if number<0 else 'zero'`

Comment: @mozway Two seconds, I wonder if that's a record for the same solution.

Comment: You could print the positive etc... without storing it as `Value`

Comment: @mozway. What do you think about the hack below? :-)

Comment: @Corralien I think this might just confuse the beginner :p Of note, python 3.10 now has a new [match/case](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching) statement

Answer (score 1):

A hack with a dictionary:

```
d = {-1: 'Negative', 0: 'Zero', 1: 'Positive'}

Number = int(input("Enter your number: "))

Value = d[Number and Number / abs(Number)]
```

```
>>> Number=5; d[Number and Number / abs(Number)]
'Positive'

>>> Number=-8; d[Number and Number / abs(Number)]
'Negative'

>>> Number=0; d[Number and Number / abs(Number)]
'Zero'
```

Obviously the right answer is given by @mozway and @sj95126.

```
>>> Value = 'Positive' if Number>0 else 'Negative' if Number<0 else 'Zero'
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your code is quite simple,
Secondly You have used Multiple if's instead of an else-if-structure, but the other two checks should be in a elif & else block. Because the nature of a number can be either Negative, Positive or Zero but not more than 1 state.

You can have a ternary expression using the ternary operator, & you can handle assigning value to a variable in one line!
Here is a function:

```py
def checkNumberNature(n):
   value = "Positive" if n > 0 else "Negative" if n < 0 else "Zero"
   print(value)
```